# Stash output in xml template

Tags: stash, xml

I have a xml template with an embedded stash xml partial. But I'm not getting any output.

This is my xml:

```
{stash:embed:viewmodels:categories process="inline" stash:entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <category_sport_name_ms>
    {exp:stash:get_list name="export_categories" match="#sport#" against="type"}
    <str><![CDATA[{name}]]></str>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </category_sport_name_ms>
```

And this is my viewmodel categories.xml (also tried html)

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="export_categories" parse_tags="yes"}
{exp:gwcode_categories group_id="2" entry_id="{stash:entry_id}" style="linear"}
    {stash:type}sport{/stash:type}
    {stash:name}{cat_name}{/stash:name}
    {stash:id}{cat_id}{/stash}
    {stash:color}{cat_description}{/stash:color}
    {stash:url}{cat_url_title}{/stash:url}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
{exp:gwcode_categories group_id="1" entry_id="{stash:entry_id}" style="linear"}
    {stash:type}age{/stash:type}
    {stash:name}{cat_name}{/stash:name}
    {stash:id}{cat_id}{/stash:id}
    {stash:url}{cat_url_title}{/stash:url}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
{exp:gwcode_categories group_id="3" entry_id="{stash:entry_id}" style="linear"}
    {stash:type}theme{/stash:type}
    {stash:name}{cat_name}{/stash:name}
    {stash:id}{cat_id}{/stash:id}
    {stash:url}{cat_url_title}{/stash:url}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

{/exp:stash:set_list}

Even if I remove the set list and just enter something like test there is still no output? Is xml unsupported? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're essentially using the embed as a snippet, so you could do this:

```
{!-- viewmodels/categories.html - include the code but don't parse --}
{stash:embed:viewmodels:categories process="start" parse="no"}
<category_sport_name_ms>
{exp:stash:get_list name="export_categories" match="#^sport$#" against="type"}
<str><![CDATA[{name}]]></str>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
</category_sport_name_ms>
```

In viewmodels/categories.html, just use `{entry_id}` instead of `{stash:entry_id}`.

You also need to ensure that your list columns are consistent for every row. That means you must use the same column names for each of your three uses of `gwcode_categories`:

```
{stash:type}sport{/stash:type}
{stash:name}{cat_name}{/stash:name}
{stash:id}{cat_id}{/stash}
{stash:color}{cat_description}{/stash:color}
{stash:url}{cat_url_title}{/stash:url}
```

(Leave the value empty if it doesn't exist)

Comment: Hi Mark, I thought this would work, but actually it isn't. All of this happens in a channel entries loop. I just can't get results. Hmmm. Maybe you know what's going on? I also tried process inline, but that doesn't work too.